# Django MVT - altering form before going into form validation

Tags: django

My app is a Django MVT app (not REST Framework) and I am trying to create a template which requests photos from the user's camera.

In my model, I have two ImageFields (which would represent those two photos):

```
photo1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/user', null=True)
photo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/user', null=True)
```

In my form, I declared them as TextInputs as follows:

```
'photo1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': INPUT_DEFAULT_CLASS, 'disabled': True}),
            'photo2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': INPUT_DEFAULT_CLASS, 'disabled': True}),
```

The reason I wanted them to be Text is because if it was a FileField and a user took a photo, I couldn't add the photo programatically into the FileField (because FileField is translated into a input type="file", which cannot be mutated through JS).

So I add the file as a encoded base 64 png file into this Text Input and I want to process in order to make it ready for the ImageField from the model.

In my form, I tried to do it like this, in the clean() method:

```
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        photo1_data = self.data['photo1']
        photo2_data = self.data['photo2']

        if photo1_data and photo2_data:
            date_str = datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
            username = cleaned_data['username']

            photo1_image = base64.b64decode(photo1_data.split(';base64,')[1])
            photo1_file = ContentFile(photo1_image, name=f"{date_str}_{username}_photo1.png")
            photo1_uploaded = InMemoryUploadedFile(photo1_file, None, f"{photo1_file.name}", 'image/png', photo1_file.tell, None)

            photo2_image = base64.b64decode(photo2_data.split(';base64,')[1])
            photo2_file = ContentFile(photo2_image, name=f"{date_str}_{username}_photo2.png")
            photo2_uploaded = InMemoryUploadedFile(photo2_file, None, f"{photo2_file.name}", 'image/png', photo2_file.tell, None)

            cleaned_data['photo1'] = photo1_uploaded
            cleaned_data['photo2'] = photo2_uploaded
            return cleaned_data
```

but in my view, on the form_invalid method:

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
        super().form_invalid(form)
        print(form.errors)
```

I get

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>photo1<ul class="errorlist"><li>No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.</li></ul></li><li>photo2<ul class="errorlist"><li>No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

So how can I make this base 64 encoded string go into the ImageField properly?

Thanks.